# Why does opening new zsh terminal print environment vars

Tags: mac-osx, zsh

Each time I open a new terminal in Mac OS, it prints a selection (but not all) of my environment vars. I use zsh shell. e.g

```
EDITOR=nano
HOME=/Users/xxxx
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LESS=-R
LOGNAME=xxxx
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
LS_COLORS='di=1;36:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=30;41:sg=30;46:tw=30;42:ow=30;43'
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=3
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.UHkqxMAS4R/Listeners
TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=447
TERM_SESSION_ID=8D1EB9B1-1C23-4EAC-BC52-DB90C5D41625
TMPDIR=/var/folders/6g/5p5g9sxn4m94j8cnk4hkx_x80000gn/T/
USER=xxxx
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
ZSH=/Users/xxxx/.oh-my-zsh
_CE_CONDA=''
_CE_M=''
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
```

I tried removing zsh and reinstalling and this hasn't fixed it. The same happens when I `source .zshrc`.

Comment: Does your `.zshrc` contain a line with `env`? (also probably better asked on unix or superuser as this question is probably off topic for Server Fault)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't sure which of the Stack Exchange universe would be the best. There are no `env` lines in the the `.zshrc` file.

Comment: Is it just environment variables or all variables. My guess would be `local`, `typeset` or `export` somewhere, followed by `$var` where just `var` was intended.

Comment: Thanks! It was solved over on the Unix stack https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741190/why-does-opening-new-zsh-terminal-print-environment-vars